# Multiple SQL JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have to make a query from two table, so for example here is my table structure for "student" table:

```
-------------------------------------------
id  |  Name  |  mom_job_id  |  dad_job_id
-------------------------------------------
1   | Test1  | 1            |  2
2   | Test2  | 3            |  1
-------------------------------------------
```

and I have "job" table like this :

```
---------------------------
id  | job_name
---------------------------
1   | designer
2   | writer
3   | programmer
---------------------------
```

I want to select a record on student table and replace "mom_job_id" and "dad_job_id" with job_name on "job table"

I have tried this query :

```
SELECT student.id, job.job_name as mom_job, job.job_name as dad_job
FROM student
INNER JOIN job ON mom_job_id = job.id
WHERE id=1
```

That query work fine, but dad's job is set to be same as mom's job, so I add another INNER JOIN and make the query like so :

```
SELECT student.id, job.job_name as mom_job, job.job_name as dad_job
FROM student
INNER JOIN job ON mom_job_id = job.id
INNER JOIN job ON dad_job_id = job.id
WHERE id=1
```

The query is work but not returned any record. So how do I solve this? I belive the problem came from the job.id

Comment: how are you not getting an ambiguous column error on your where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with this one, just give the job table a different alias each time you JOIN it.

```
SELECT s.id, job_mom.job_name as mom_job, job_dad.job_name as dad_job
FROM student s
INNER JOIN job job_mom ON s.mom_job_id = job_mom.id
INNER JOIN job job_dad ON s.dad_job_id = job_dad.id
WHERE s.id=1
```

In the event that the job table JOIN does not return a row and you still want to show student table data, you can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT s.id, job_mom.job_name as mom_job, job_dad.job_name as dad_job
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN job job_mom ON s.mom_job_id = job_mom.id
LEFT JOIN job job_dad ON s.dad_job_id = job_dad.id
WHERE s.id=1
```

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 Work perfectly, but when dad_job or mom_job on student table not listed on job table, it's not returned any record. Should i use another join?

Comment: use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to always return a row for each record in the student table. I've updated my answer to fit your updated requirements.

Comment: @MattBusche i'll try that, thanks for the answer, but your first answer didn't solve my problem :)

Comment: @ArionaRian my first answer was an exact replica of this one with different alias names

Comment: well thank for all answer made, I appreciate that very much! thanks :)

Comment: Edit made to reflect LEFT JOIN question.

Comment: @MattBusche for the sake of argument, your first answer used student.id as a JOIN condition, so it was different.

Answer (score 2):

You need to alias your job table since you're referencing it twice.

Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will always pull in a row for each matching record in the student table. If there is no matching record in the job table for mom or dad then that column will return a `NULL` value.

```
SELECT s.id, mom.job_name as mom_job, dad.job_name as dad_job
FROM student s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN job mom ON s.mom_job_id = mom.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN job dad ON s.dad_job_id = dad.id
WHERE s.id = 1
```